# Newly created sheets keeps getting deleted - Python/Pandas/Openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

In the code below, I create some new sheets including a sheet called "Calculation" using:

```
wb.create_sheet("Calculation")
```

But for some reason, this sheet gets created in the beginning but it gets deleted towards the end. I print sheet names twice in this code, the first time it show all sheets including "Calculation" & the second time it show every sheet except "Calculation"

What am I doing wrong. see the code and output below

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

def main():
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('inv.xlsx')
    wb.create_sheet("Calculation")
    Calculation = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Calculation")
    dailyvalsum = price['dailyval'].sum()
    totalvalsum = price['totalval'].sum()
    print(dailyvalsum)
    print(totalvalsum)

    Calculation['B3'] = dailyvalsum
    Calculation['B4'] = totalvalsum
    print(wb.get_sheet_names())
  

    sum_col = (price["Yearly Demand"]/48)/5
    price["Daily"] = sum_col
    daily = price["Daily"]
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('inv.xlsx')
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('inv.xlsx', engine="openpyxl")
    writer.book = wb
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in wb.worksheets)
    daily.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Daily", index=True)
    writer.save()
    writer.close()


    Avail = (price["Warehouse Balance"] + price["Assembly Line Balance"])
    price["Avail"] = Avail
    Availbal = price["Avail"]
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('inv.xlsx')
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('inv.xlsx', engine="openpyxl")
    writer.book = wb
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in wb.worksheets)
    Availbal.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Avail", index=True)
    writer.save()
    writer.close()

    daysofinv = (price["Avail"]/price["Daily"])
    price["daysofinv"] = daysofinv
    daysinv = price["daysofinv"]
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('inv.xlsx')
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('inv.xlsx', engine="openpyxl")
    writer.book = wb
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in wb.worksheets)
    daysinv.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Daysofinv", index=True)
    writer.save()
    writer.close()

    totalval = (price["Avail"]*price["Unit Price"])
    price["totalval"] = totalval
    totalvalue = price["totalval"]
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('inv.xlsx')
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('inv.xlsx', engine="openpyxl")
    writer.book = wb
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in wb.worksheets)
    totalvalue.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Total Value", index=True)
    writer.save()
    writer.close()


    dailyval = price["totalval"] / price["daysofinv"]
    price['dailyval'] = dailyval
    dailyvalue = price['dailyval']
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('inv.xlsx')
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('inv.xlsx', engine="openpyxl")
    writer.book = wb
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in wb.worksheets)
    dailyvalue.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Daily value", index=True)
    writer.save()
    writer.close()

    print("Done")
    print(wb.get_sheet_names())
    wb.save("inv.xlsx")

main()
```

Output:

```
36433.74620833334
365574.97000000003
['Price', 'Parts', 'Daily', 'Avail', 'Daysofinv', 'Total Value', 'Daily value', 'Calculation']
Done
['Price', 'Parts', 'Daily', 'Avail', 'Daysofinv', 'Total Value', 'Daily value']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like after `wb.create_sheet("Calculation")`, you then call `wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('inv.xlsx')` without saving the workbook. By doing this you're overwriting what you just created with the stored notebook. Try commenting out all but the first `wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('inv.xlsx')` lines; multiple calls might not be necessary depending on what you're trying to to. And if multiple calls are necessary, you might try repeating your `.save .close` pattern before your block of code operating on the "Daily" sheet.